# How to make neovim automatically convert the parameters of the command into strings?

Tags: neovim

I want to make a command:

```
command -nargs=1 Demo lua print <args>
```

I have the following problem when I execute it:

```
Demo test
nil
```

I had to put double quotes around the parameter to make it work:

```
Demo "test"
test
```

How can I let neovim automatically add double quotes to the parameters

Comment: Can you update the example so that output actually matches the command you run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the problem is that the placeholders for the parameters are not used correctly.

Instead of using `<args>`, you should use `<q-args>`, which can treat parameters as strings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).